# Send data from one landing page to other landing page in marketo

Tags: php, marketo

I am new in marketo, can anyone help me out?
I have created two landing pages. The first page I created have form in it and other page is a simple landing page. The problem is that I want to send data values from one landing page to other when user click the submit button and print these data values to that page. But I don't know how to send form data from one landing page to other in MARKETO.
I have searched on google but didn't get the right answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the form data from your first page, to the second page using query string parameters. There is an article [here](https://learn.uberflip.com/marketo/using-query-string-parameters-with-marketo)  and also one [here](http://mxp.getmura.com/blog/sending-custom-querystrings-to-marketo/) that might help.